# Add progress dialog in to the action bar sherlock from sherlock fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Is there any way to add progress dialog in to the action bar sherlock from `sherlock fragment` (not fragment activity). I have to use sherlock fragments because in my application I use navigation drawer.
For the fragment activity, progress dialog works fine when I use following code.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
setContentView(R.layout.search_all_fragment_layout);              
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

Is there any way to do this in Fragments ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ProgressBar can be shown by using this lines in your Activity:

```
supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminate(true);
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

If you wanna use it in your Fragment you have to refer to the Activity:

```
getActivity().supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
getActivity().setSupportProgressBarIndeterminate(true);
getActivity().setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

Consider making a method in your Activity which you call from the Fragment.

EDIT:

Have a method in your Activity like this:

```
public void activateProgressBar(boolean activite){
    setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(activate);
}
```

Make sure you called this in your onCreate() of the Activity:

```
supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminate(true);
```

Now just call this in your Fragment:

```
((YourActivity)getActivity()).activateProgressBar(true / false);
```

Comment: first thanks for the answer, can you please explain what do you mean by this line
"Consider making a method in your Activity which you call from the Fragment."

Comment: in fragment I cannot use this getActivity().activateProgressBar(true);
it says that "The method activateProgressBar(boolean) is undefined for the type FragmentActivity" what can I do for this

Comment: Thank you very much for the descriptive answer and spending your time on this matter, It is working now